# Make only collapsed portion of div clickable - expanded section should remain unclickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a nested div that contains 'additional information'.

When a person clicks the div, it opens the 'additional information' div.

I have used `.stopPropagation()` to prevent it from closing when the person clicks the text in the 'additional information', but if they click the borders or something, the collapse happens and the information goes away.

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339312/jquery-or-any-possible-to-make-only-a-part-of-a-div-clickable) - which was seemingly close to what I wanted, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work exactly how I need.

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/djLjPe) of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```js
$('#collapsDiv').on('show.bs.collapse', function( event ) {
 event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Only happen when outter div is opened');
})
$('#collapseDiv').on('hide.bs.collapse', function( event ) {
 event.stopPropagation();
 console.log('Only happen when outter div is collapsed');
})
$('#additionalDiv').on('click', function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
})

$('#collapseDiv').click(function(e) {
     if (e.pageY > $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()) {
          // bottom was clicked
          console.log('bottom clicked!');
          e.stopPropagation();
     } else {
          // up of the div was clicked
          console.log('top clicked');
     }
});
```

```css
#collapseDiv {
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
 <div id="collapseDiv" class="alert alert-warning" data-toggle="collapse" href="#additionalDiv" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="additionalDiv">
  This Div shows by default - I used an alert to make it more visually obvious. Only this part should remain clickable. The hidden stuff should not be clickable. A bonus would be having the lower portion not have a pointer!
  <div id="additionalDiv" class="collapse">
   <div class="other-stuff">
    <h2>This stuff should not be clickable</h2>
    <p>There may be paragraphs here a user might want to copy/paste!</p>
    <p>In a perfect world - even the bottom / sides would not trigger the collapse. This would only be collapsed by clicking the original div area.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This is 'working', but it only avoids clicks on the bottom - how would I make it avoid clicks on the sides as well?

side note: it seems there is about a very tiny row on the bottom that causes it to collapse if clicked still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *padding* space makes it clickable.

You don't need javascript to achieve this. Just add another `div` for toggling *only*.

```css
#collapseDiv { 
  padding: 0;
}

.my-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px;
}

#additionalDiv {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div id="collapseDiv" class="alert alert-warning">
    <div class="my-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#additionalDiv" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="additionalDiv">
      This Div shows by default - I used an alert to make it more visually obvious. Only this part should remain clickable. The
      hidden stuff should not be clickable. A bonus would be having the lower portion not have a pointer!
    </div>
    
    <div id="additionalDiv" class="collapse">
      <div class="other-stuff">
        <h2>This stuff should not be clickable</h2>
        <p>There may be paragraphs here a user might want to copy/paste!</p>
        <p>In a perfect world - even the bottom / sides would not trigger the collapse. This would only be collapsed by clicking
          the original div area.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you try it in the codepen, even adding that to `#collapseDiv` there is still a tiny spot at the bottom that causes it to collapse

Answer (score 0):

I would adjust a couple things - get the additional div outside of the clickable one and put the padding on the sub-containers and styling on the container.

The problem really is that your container padding is clickable around the collapsable div.

```
.container--nopad {
    padding: 0;
}

#collapseDiv, #additionalDiv {
    padding: 20px;
}


<div class="container container--nopad alert alert-warning">
    <div id="collapseDiv"  data-toggle="collapse" href="#additionalDiv" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="additionalDiv">
        This Div shows by default - I used an alert to make it more visually obvious. Only this part should remain clickable. The hidden stuff should not be clickable. A bonus would be having the lower portion not have a pointer!
    </div>
    <div id="additionalDiv" class="collapse">
        <div class="other-stuff">
            <h2>This stuff should not be clickable</h2>
            <p>There may be paragraphs here a user might want to copy/paste!</p>
            <p>In a perfect world - even the bottom / sides would not trigger the collapse. This would only be collapsed by clicking the original div area.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/dmgig/pen/EpzGLG

Comment: Semantically, it is probably good to keep the "button" separate from the element it is acting on.

Answer (score 0):

the padding from the container div is what is causing the action. remove the padding and instead add it to both inner elements.

```js
$('#collapsDiv').on('show.bs.collapse', function( event ) {
 event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Only happen when outter div is opened');
})
$('#collapseDiv').on('hide.bs.collapse', function( event ) {
 event.stopPropagation();
 console.log('Only happen when outter div is collapsed');
})
$('#additionalDiv').on('click', function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
})

$('#collapseDiv').click(function(e) {
     if (e.pageY > $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()) {
          // bottom was clicked
          console.log('bottom clicked!');
          e.stopPropagation();
     } else {
          // up of the div was clicked
          console.log('top clicked');
     }
});
```

```css
 #collapseDiv {
 cursor:pointer;
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
}
#collapseDiv .triggerDiv, 
#collapseDiv #additionalDiv {
 padding-left: 1.25rem;
 padding-right: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
 <div id="collapseDiv" class="alert alert-warning" data-toggle="collapse" href="#additionalDiv" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="additionalDiv">
  <div class="triggerDiv">This Div shows by default - I used an alert to make it more visually obvious. Only this part should remain clickable. The hidden stuff should not be clickable. A bonus would be having the lower portion not have a pointer!</div>
  <div id="additionalDiv" class="collapse">
   <div class="other-stuff">
    <h2>This stuff should not be clickable</h2>
    <p>There may be paragraphs here a user might want to copy/paste!</p>
    <p>In a perfect world - even the bottom / sides would not trigger the collapse. This would only be collapsed by clicking the original div area.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```